# Lazarus: Работа со сканером Штрих-Кода, принимать данные с COM-порта

Tags: pascal, поиск-библиотек, lazarus, com-порт, barcode

> Lazarus. Задача №1: Написать программу с помощью которой можно будет определить повторяющиеся дисконтные карты. Процесс: Пользователь берёт стопку карт и последовательно их сканирует. Задача программы загореться красным цветом на пол.секунды если будет совпадение новой отсканированной карты с ранее отсканированными. Если пользователь замечает что программа покраснела, он откладывает карту для её дальнейшей утилизации.

ГЛАВНЫЙ вопрос: какую библиотеку использовать? И пример кода для получения данных с COM - порта.

Comment: Для чтения штрих-кодов есть [ZXing.Delphi](https://github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi) и её частичный порт на FPC: [ZXing.Lazarus](https://github.com/cutec-chris/ZXing.Lazarus). Для работы с com-портом есть [TLazSerial](https://github.com/JurassicPork/TLazSerial). Всё гуглится за пару минут.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. И за "Гуглится за пару минут" потому что мало найти какое-то слово, это должна быть рабочая ссылка на рабочие файлы (так сказать валидное всё должно быть) - а это уже не "пару минут". К тому же кроме найти ещё нужно как-то этим воспользоваться. Так вот код:

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  port: string;
begin
  port := edit2.text;
  lazSerial1.Device:=port;
  lazSerial1.Open;     // открытие порта сканера
  label1.Caption:='порт открыт';
end; 

procedure TForm1.LazSerial1RxData(Sender: TObject);
var
  s : string;
begin
  s := lazSerial1.ReadData;       // чтение информации сканером и запись в перем

  if s <> '' then                 // скромное условие
  begin
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + s;       // запись в Список в строку  без разбиения на буквы
  label1.Caption:='Успешно внесено в список';
  end;
end;

Answer (score 0):

Вот код рабочий:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  port: string;
begin
  port := edit2.text;
  lazSerial1.Device:=port;
  lazSerial1.Open;     // открытие порта сканера
  label1.Caption:='порт открыт';
end; 

procedure TForm1.LazSerial1RxData(Sender: TObject);
var
  s : string;
begin
  s := lazSerial1.ReadData;       // чтение информации сканером и запись в перем

  if s <> '' then                 // скромное условие
  begin
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + s;       // запись в Список в строку  без разбиения на буквы
  label1.Caption:='Успешно внесено в список';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Я использовал TLazSerial. Установка производится таким путём: Распаковываем в папку C:\lazarus\components\ (по умолчанию). Затем запускаем Lazarus, меню Пакет - Открыть файл пакета .lpk - выбираем в директории файл - компилировать - Добавить Установить.

Comment: а если несколько сканеров по com?